# Xenu Link Sleuth through a proxy server

Tags: c#, html, seo, xenu

I have a client who needs to periodically check an internet site I've developed for them, for broken links.  They need to do this from their local company network.

They have internet access and can browse the web using Internet Explorer, but Xenu won't connect to any internet sites.  I think it's because the company have a proxy server at 192.168.xxx.xxx:8080, which Internet Explorer is using.

Does anyone know how to configure Xenu to go through a proxy server?  Xenu's help file isn't very helpful.

Comment: Did you, or did you not, try this? http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html#FAQ , question #6

Comment: If you mean section 6 "How can I configure a proxy" then yes - I've tried setting "Use HTTP 1.1 through proxy connections" in the advanced tab of the internet options, but the other instructions don't make sense to me.  I'm not aware of any "control application" in Windows and if it means the control panel --> Internet properties, then the proxy server is already configured in the Local Area Network (LAN) Settings.  Use a proxy server for your LAN is checked, the correct IP address and port has been entered and bypass proxy server for local addressess is checked.

Comment: Aha, that's good to know. Is there any authentication needed on the proxy server?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would think so.  You aren't asked to authenticate when you open and use internet explorer, so I would expect it's picking up the credentials of the logged on user.  I would have thought Xenu would do the same, but I'll ask the server team the question to see if it's an issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client could instead use Screaming Frog SEO Spider http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/ - it's free for up to 500 pages and provides proxy support.

Comment: Thanks CodeBuddy.  I took a look at Screaming Frog and this suits my client's needs much better than Xenu Link Sleuth.  It perofrms lots of useful analysis, including checking for broken links, and as you stated - it works through a proxy!